# with the raspberry pi with win10 is it possible to get cpu usage

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I'm running win10 on the raspberry pi 2.  Using C# (and universal apps), I'm wondering if there is a way to get cpu usage or memory usage?

my guess is 'no' as I don't seem to have access to PerformanceCounters, but perhaps there is a hack that i'm not yet aware of?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the data used by the webpage mentioned by sending a HTTP GET request on port 80 to http://[yourpi]/api/resourcemanager/systemperf. This will return you a block of JSON. This is documented on the device at http://[yourpi]/restdocumentation.htm.

P/Invoke of GetNativeSystemInfo failed on my IoT device. The error indicated that it couldn't find kernel32.dll. The same code worked as expected on my Win10 desktop.

I will ask the product group about accessing performance data programmatically.

Mark Radbourne (MSFT)

Comment: I had a similar issue with the p/invoke and found a reference somewhere saying that information is not currently available.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a HTTP Server is running on Port 80 of the RPi2 with W10. Just open your webbrowser, type in your RPi's IP, login and click on Performance (http://raspberrypi/SystemPerformance.htm). There you go! 
If you'ld like to generate a Performance Profile, go to Perf-Tracing (http://raspberrypi/xperf.htm).

Comment: is there a way to get this programmatically?  well, other than opening an http session and doing some scraping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is working, but you could give `GetNativeSystemInfo` a try.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SYSTEM_INFO
{
    public ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
    public ushort wReserved;
    public uint dwPageSize;
    public IntPtr lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    public IntPtr lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
    public UIntPtr dwActiveProcessorMask;
    public uint dwNumberOfProcessors;
    public uint dwProcessorType;
    public uint dwAllocationGranularity;
    public ushort wProcessorLevel;
    public ushort wProcessorRevision;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(ref SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);
```

Details can be found here: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)